# Symfony redirect url with pagination param

Tags: php, symfony, redirect, routes, symfony-3.3

On my Symfony project I have this controller:

```
class MyListController extends Controller
{
  public function myListRedirectAction($page)
  {
    //How I will set ? params
    $url=$this->generateUrl('my_list');
    $response=new RedirectResponse($url);

    return $response;
  }

  public function myListAction()
  {
    $paginationIndex=$request->query->get('page');
    //Get List
  }
}
```

I also have this routes (using php way):

```
$list=new Route('/list',array(
    '_controller'=>'AppBundle:MyList:myList'
));
$collection->add('my_list',$list);


$listRedirect=new Route('/list/{page}',array(
    '_controller'=>'AppBundle:MyList:myListRedirect'
),array(
  'page'=>'\d+'
));
$collection->add('my_list_redirect',$list);
```

Whan I try to achieve is to redirect all requests eg. `/list/1` into `/list?page=1` but when I generate url from route need to generate the url from a route I need to set the url parameters after `?` part.

DO you knwo how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('route_name', ['params']));
```

`$this->redirect()` will return `RedirectResponse` instance , and `$this->generateUrl()` will generate string based on your routing configuration.

So in your case this should work:

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('my_list_redirect', ['page' => 1]));
```